# Cardinality of the set of internal sets

Tags: solution-verification, cardinals, nonstandard-analysis

Non standard analysis relies on using sets that have the same properties as sets of real numbers to transfer many good theorems over. Every set $S\in P(\Bbb R)$ has a unique extension $S^* \in P(\Bbb R^*)$. $P(\Bbb R)^*$ clearly has the same number of elements as $P(\Bbb R)$ seeing as it’s defined by a bijection, but set of internal sets is a superset of that and a subset of $P(\Bbb R^*)$.

$|P(\Bbb R)| < |I|< |P(\Bbb R^*)|$ where I is the set of internal subsets. This sandwiched inequality along with the fact that the leftmost and rightmost sides are equal, should prove that $I$ has cardinality $2^c$.

Is there any error in this proof or something I missed that could make it faster?

Comment: Your $<$s should be $\le$s. (Also, a minor quibble: it's not necessarily the case that $P(\mathbb{R})$ and $P(\mathbb{R}^*)$ have the same cardinality. More precisely, this is true for some but not all hyperreal fields $\mathbb{R}^*$ - e.g. all such which are constructed via an ultrapower over $\mathbb{N}$.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber But the construction is a quotient of $\Bbb R^N$ which has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$. Through a similar sand which argument, all hyperreal fields must have the same cardinality. This argument is written out in the Wikipedia page for the hyperreals.

Comment: "But the construction is a quotient of $\mathbb{R}^N$." That's **one way**, but not the **only** way, to build a hyperreal field. "Through a similar sand which argument, all hyperreal fields must have the same cardinality." That's incorrect. There are hyperreal fields of arbitrarily large cardinality (for example: rather than $\mathbb{R}^N$, use $\mathbb{R}^X$ for some large-as-you-like set $X$). The wiki page isn't great about this, and if memory serves it seems to imply that the $\mathbb{R}^N$-approach is the only one. But that's not true.

Comment: In fact, the wikipedia page later makes it clear that there are other constructions: look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number#Hyperreal_fields.